# Is it safe to remove android system images?

Tags: android

I have `Android Studo` installed on my `Ubuntu 14.04` machine and the android system images use up a lot of space:

```
5771    ./android-23
4200    ./android-21
3146    ./android-22
13116   .
```

Do I need all of them or is it safe to remove the older ones? And if, how to remove them properly (which menu/action to use in `Android Studio`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can delete any you don't want to use anymore i already delete my all system image before jelly bean (API 16) because same reason as yours taking too much space now i only keep which i will use for testing and running my app with android studio

Yes you can delete via SDK or Delete directly it will not make any issue